# Получение разницы в ценах в диапазоне двух дат

Tags: sql, postgresql

Имеется таблица куда раз в сутки добавляются строки, где содержится ID продукта, его цена, название и время в которое была добавлена строка.

```
CREATE TABLE products (
    id integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    product_id integer NOT NULL,
    title text NOT NULL,
    price double precision NOT NULL,
    checked_at timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now()
);
```

Данные в таблице `products` выглядят таким образом:

| id | product_id | title | price | checked_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **1000** | **Арбуз** | **50** | **2022-07-19 10:00:00** |
| **2** | **2000** | **Яблоко** | **30** | **2022-07-19 10:00:00** |
| **3** | **3000** | **Груша** | **20** | **2022-07-19 10:00:00** |
| 4 | 1000 | Арбуз | 100 | 2022-07-20 10:00:00 |
| 5 | 2000 | Яблоко | 50 | 2022-07-20 10:00:00 |
| 6 | 3000 | Груша | 35 | 2022-07-20 10:00:00 |
| 7 | 1000 | Арбуз | 150 | 2022-07-21 10:00:00 |
| 8 | 2000 | Яблоко | 50 | 2022-07-21 10:00:00 |
| 9 | 3000 | Груша | 60 | 2022-07-21 10:00:00 |

Мне необходимо передавать диапазон дат (к примеру от 2022-07-19 до 2022-07-21) и получать разницу в ценах всех уникальных продуктов, то есть ответ должен быть такой:

| product_id | title | price_difference |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | Арбуз | 100 |
| 2000 | Яблоко | 20 |
| 3000 | Груша | 40 |

Я разобрался только с самым началом, где мне необходимо получить ID всех уникальных товаров в таблице с помощью `DISTINCT`.
Дальше мне необходимо найти строки, которые ближе всего к диапазону дат.

Comment: JOIN двух копий таблицы, каждая со своей датой, и вычитание.

Comment: *мне необходимо получить ID всех уникальных товаров в таблице* А нафига оно надо? *строки, которые ближе всего к диапазону дат* А какой критерий у этой "ближести"?

Comment: @Akina, у меня в таблице содержатся ID товаров с повторениями. Я думаю, что для составления запроса необходимо сначала получить список всех товаров без повторений.

Comment: Совершенно незачем. Этот список сам вылезет.

Comment: @Akina, тогда окей. 
По поводу критерия "ближести": когда мы делаем SELECT, где `WHERE checked_at BETWEEN '2022-07-19'::timestamp AND '2022-07-21'::timestamp;` необходимо получить самую верхнюю строку каждого продукта к первой дате и самую последнюю строку каждого продукта ко второй дате, чтобы между ними найти разницу. Не знаю как более правильно это объяснить.

Comment: Мне кажется это неправильным. По сути тебе надо разницу действующих на заданные моменты начала и конца периода цен. То есть что для начала, что для конца периода тебе требуется последняя цена на дату, не превышающую заданную (т.е. именно эту дату либо ближайшую предыдущую). По-моему, так. Ведь то, что цены скидываются ежедневно, не гарантирует "дыр" с пропущенными значениями. Или наличие цены на любую дату - гарантировано, и возможности существования пропущенных значений не следует предусматривать?

Comment: @Akina, наличие цены на любую дату не гарантировано и есть возможность существования пропущенных значений.
Спасибо за объяснение, но всё равно не могу структурировать в голове.

Comment: Ну вот дана тебе дата. Скажем, '2022-07-21'. Что надо сделать, чтобы получить цену на эту дату? видимо, взять все цены, где дата не больше заданной, отсортировать по убыванию дат, и взять только первую запись для каждого продукта. Если проделать это дважды, получатся записи с актуальными ценами на начало и конец периода. Осталось связать по продукту и вычесть.

Comment: Да, для сортировки и взятия только первой записи разумнее использовать ROW_NUMBER() в CTE.

Comment: @Akina, *и взять только первую запись для каждого продукта*
Разве мне не надо для этого ID всех уникальных товаров, чтобы знать какие записи брать?

Comment: Нет. Я же сказал - использовать ROW_NUMBER(), а у ней есть такая штука как PARTITION BY.